# SOAP Request send empty body

Tags: php, xml, soap, wsdl

I can't find out where is the problem, I have prepared an XML for sending through the SOAP Client like so:

```
$client = new SoapClient($url, array(
    'trace' => true,
    "style"    => SOAP_RPC,
    "use"      => SOAP_ENCODED
));

$response = $client->sendItems($xml);

var_dump($client->__getLastRequest());
```

`var_dump` shows me `string(233) " "`, but when I'm testing it throught the PHPStorm Rest Client testing tool, it shows me this:

```
string(233) "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://externalsite.com/ltm/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:sendItemsRequest/></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
"
```

There are no content inside the body. I triple-checked that my `$xml` contains the full XML with bodycontent.

Anyone got similiar problem before or have some idea what's going on ?

**==== UPDATED ====**

Here is the XML Content:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ltm="http://externalsite.com/ltm/">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
    <ltm:sendItemsRequest>
        <ItemsToAdd>
            <ItemToAdd>
                <description>DEMO DESCRIPTION text</description>
                <url>http://localhost/media/items/0000000001.jpg</url>
                <brand>BRANDTEST</brand>
                <status>creation</status>
                <statusDate>1423209737</statusDate>
                <beginDate>1406844000</beginDate>
                <endDate>1730329200</endDate>
                <targets>
                        <barcode>1234567891011</barcode>
                        <barcode>9876543210123</barcode>
                </targets>
                <medias>
                    <media>
                        <retailer>RETAILERTEST</retailer>
                        <format>dummyformat</format>
                    </media>
                </medias>
            </ItemToAdd>
        </ItemsToAdd>
    </ltm:sendItemsRequest>
</soapenv:Body>
```

Comment: @aspireinemaga,Can you share us your xml request

Comment: @user3040610 - added to updated section. thanks

Comment: @aspireinemaga- check your xml structure <sendItemsRequest> is closed with </sendCouponsRequest>,tags are not correctly closed.

Comment: sorry for wrong code, i just misstyped it here, but in my XML its fine, no mixing ... i've updated the question

Comment: @aspirinemaga - Hi, I have also encountered with the same issue. Were you able to fix this? If yes, could you please tell, how did you fix it ?

Comment: @amit4497 - sorry, but I absolutely can't recall what was the solution, but I am sure I fixed it. (Maybe BOM present in the .file, try to change it to UTF8)

Comment: @dev I have the same issue, have you been able to fix it? If so, then can you please tell me how?